# Is there a way I can pass a property between components, without using the props object?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I have a component that displays a list of cafes. Within this component ( `CafeList.jsx`), an axios request is made which returns a list of cafes, which is the mapped over and rendered to the browser. 
I'd like users to be able to click on a cafe, then be directed to a page with specific information about that particular cafe (at this stage it's `CafeReview.jsx`).

I need to  pass the cafe ID (`_id`) from `CafeList` to `CafeReviews`, so that I can use it in an axios request that brings back specific data about the cafe that was clicked on. Any suggestions? Also, do I have the right general approach?

**Components**

`CafeList.jsx`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const CafeList = () => {
    const [cafes, setCafe] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/all-cafes')
        .then(cafe => {
            setCafe(cafe.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[])

    return(
            <div className = 'cafe-container-container'>
                <h2>Cafes</h2>
                {
                cafes.map(cafe =>{
                    const {cafeName,photoURL,_id} = cafe
                    
                    return (
                    <Link to = {`/cafe-reviews/${_id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                        <div className = 'cafe-container'>
                            <h2>{cafeName}</h2>
                            <img src = {photoURL}></img>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    )
                })
            }
            </div>

    )
}

export default CafeList
```

`CafeReviews.jsx`

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const CafeReviews = () => {
  const [cafe,setCafe] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/cafe/:id')
    .then(result => {
        setCafe(result.data)
    })
  },[])

  return(
      <div>
          {
             cafe.map(item => {
                 return (
                     <h2>{item.cafeName}</h2>
                 )
             }) 
          }
      </div>
  )
}

export default CafeReviews
```

**Routes and data models**

GET cafe by id:

```
app.get('/api/cafe/:id', (req,res) => {
    const id =req.params.id
    Cafe.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Cafe Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const cafeSchema = new Schema({
    cafeName:String,
    photoURL:String,
}, {timestamps:true})

const Cafe = mongoose.model('cafes', cafeSchema)

module.exports = Cafe
```

Router:

```
import React from 'react'
import AddReview from './components/AddReview'
import Main from './components/Main'
import AllReviews from './components/AllReviews'
import CafeReviews from './components/CafeReviews'
import './styles.css'

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  return(
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' exact component = {Main}/>
      <Route path ='/add-review' component = {AddReview}/>
      <Route path ='/all-reviews' component = {AllReviews}/>
      <Route path ='/cafe-reviews/:id' component = {CafeReviews}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't understand, you already have access to the cafe's ID on the reviews page, it's in the URL? You can use react router to get the ID from there and use it in the query

Comment: `axios.get('/api/cafe/:id')` doesn't look quite right. I'm sure you meant to access the `id` from the match params and construct a valid URL for the GET request.

Comment: @Jayce444 I think I get what you're saying, but would you mind elaborating? I've updated my question to include my router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the CafeReviews component is directly rendered by a `<Route/>`, by default is has all the react router props passed to it. From there you can access the params, which will contain the `:id` of that specific cafe in the URL. So try something like this:

```
const CafeReviews = ({ match }) => {
  const [cafe,setCafe] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/cafe/${match.params.id}`)
    .then(result => {
        setCafe(result.data)
    })
  },[])
```

Haven't tested, might need to check the docs `react-router-dom` to see if that's correct shape of object and such, but in general that's how to access the params inside the component